# Best practice for LIMIT MySQL php

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there is any point of using `LIMIT` in a PHP PDO MySQL query, when the result would come back with 1 row anyway (Unless something horrible went wrong). For example, given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    ID Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(25)
);
```

Would there be any performance difference between the following:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE ID=:ID");
```

or

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE ID=:ID LIMIT 1");
```

**EDIT**: So I done my own little investigation, and it seems that the difference is in the nanoseconds Lol, and neither method being faster than the other. I just put each statement in a 10000x loop, and recorded a few runs ... On a laptop too, so not scientific or anything Lol ...

Comment: You're selecting on `id`. If `id` is set to be unique then MySQL can only ever return one row. If it's not set `unique` (why not?) you could check for an error if more than one row is returned. Limiting the result set removes that possibility. As for performance: no difference that you'd notice.

Comment: Any performance difference, if any, would be in the range of microseconds which is not worth worrying about.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848390/is-there-any-point-using-mysql-limit-1-when-querying-on-indexed-unique-field

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327982/would-limit-0-1-speed-up-a-select-on-a-primary-key

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I agree with @MajidFouladpour that any difference would be minor. If you had a DB ranging in the millions of records then you might receive some delay, but at that point you're mining rows and not asking the real question of "how do i handle this much data?"

Answer (score 0):

Not much for this query, since it is on a primary key.

But if you are doing a query that is less optimized, then yes there would be some small difference between a query with a limit and one without.

Also peace of mind knowing that your query will never return more rows than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how many queries are being called per page and how many users are loading the page at any one time.

Your may only save a few nanoseconds on a single query but they all add up.

Answer (score 0):

With the clause LIMIT 1 (or more generic LIMIT offset, length) you are guaranteed to return results immediately once the LIMIT reached.

Without such a limit the execution may continue even if no more matches found - so it is less performance effective. The more complex SQL query, the more apparent difference in execution time.

In general, it is always considered a good practice to apply reasonable LIMIT clause.